# Is it possible to set user subsciption in-active after trail ends? Laravel cashier -stripe

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Here is what I have done once user register,

```
   $user->createAsStripeCustomer();

        $user->newSubscription('main', $data['plan'])
            ->trialDays(21)
            ->create();
```

as it eventually, returns user subscribed true, and it will keep after trail period too, so I mean how I'll handle this situation after trail got ended? thanks any help would be really appreciated.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the trial ends user will be on the grace period, and we can check easily if user trial is ended.

> $user->subscription('main')->onTrial()

Comment: its been answered by myself so any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Subscription and set [`cancel_at_period_end=true`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at_period_end) which will cancel the subscription at the end of the trial (the current period).

It looks like this is how Cashier does cancellations [under the hood](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/11.x/src/Subscription.php#L798), so you ought to be able to just use `cancel()` as seen in their [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing#cancelling-subscriptions).

Comment: thanks Nolan, its good Idea so at the end of trail period user subscription will get canceled, no other way right? becuase if we don't do so it keep subscription active don't know either its right approch or not or I may have ot revise my logic while adding trail period may be.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your title was "Is it possible to set user subsciption in-active after trail ends?" which is what I've addressed here. Are you trying to handle something else?

Comment: I have canceled the subscription using $user->subscription('main')->cancelNow() this immediately cancel and yours would have canceled by end of trail i.e cancel method. but the point is it stills return true in $user->subscribed('main')